# Prepending an already existing field to every element of an array in JSON

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to transform JSON data using JQ in Windows CLI. The data is in the form.

```
{
  "book": {
     "title": "Some title",
     "subtitle": "Some subtitle"
    },
  "price": "£19.99",
  "chapters": [
    {
      "Chapter_no": "1",
      "chapter_title":"foo"
      },
    {
      "Chapter_no": "2",
      "chapter_title": "bar"
      },
    {
      "Chapter_no": "3",
      "chapter_title": "foobar"
      }
    {
      "Chapter_no": "4",
      "chapter_title": "fooandbar"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to transform the data to the form.

```json
[
 {
   "title": "Some title",
   "subtitle": "Some subtitle"
   "price": "£19.99",
   "Chapter_no": "1",
   "chapter_title":"foo",
 },
 {
   "title": "Some title",
   "subtitle": "Some subtitle"
   "price": "£19.99",
   "Chapter_no": "2",
   "chapter_title":"bar",
 },
 ...
]
```

In other words display the values for `title`, `subtitle`, and `price` above every `chapter` and `chapter_no` fields.

So far I have been successful in outputting the `chapter` and `chapter_no` fields using the command:

```
type "books.json" | jq -s --raw-output ".[].chapters[] | [.chapter_no, .chapter_title]" > "books_new.json"
```

But I'm having difficulty trying to work out how to extract the fields from the previous arrays and add them to the chapter fields. I have searched the site already and as suggested tried various combinations of using `+=` but to no avail. I thought maybe I should be using `map` but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to reconstruct `chapters` than update.

```
[.book + {price} + .chapters[]]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IC0pEGIuvIr)</sup>